# Latex: is is possible to have a marginnote with a leading line and both in and outside a float environment?

Tags: floats, footnotes, labels, marginnote, todonotes

I do not have an example since I want to know if it is possible, here is the one from the wiki slightly modified.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, outer=5cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{Margin notes}

This is just random text, but random text that is not randomly typed since that would not make sense. This location\marginnote{is where I would like to have a line leading to from this margin note}. Random text.
\end{document}
```

My objective is to have a line connecting the **location** word or the space after it to the margin note, so that there is a quick way to relate it to the margin note, a footnote does not solve my issue since it would reduce the vertical space of the template that I need to use.

I believe that if it is not possible to have a line doing the linking, a valid possibility would be to just have a numbered reference similar to the pair ***\label*** and ***\ref***.

Thanks in advance!
Best,
Carlos

**Edit**
Thanks to @samcarter I was able to use:

```
usepackage[backgroundcolor=white,linecolor=red,bordercolor=none]{todonotes}
```

To solve my question, however, this implementation breaks while inside a float (specifically a figure), I tried in the caption and got a "not in par mode" error, anyone got an idea for that?

Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe the `todonotes` package could help

Comment: @samcarter Thanks a lot!
I was able to get what I wanted using
    
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=white,linecolor=red,bordercolor=none]{todonotes}

Comment: unrelated but it's best not to use `\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}` (makes the document non portable, doesn't work with pdflatex for example)

Comment: @CMichael Good to hear you were able to solve your problem! It would be nice if you could add a short answer below so that future users with the same question can benefit from your solution.

Comment: todonotes uses internally \marginpar which doesn't work in a figure. If you don't need \marginpar you could do \let\marginpar\marginnote. Then it should work.

Comment: Answered my question with your help, samcarter and UlrikeFischer. Thanks!



DavidCarlisle, it was just the example from wiki, I adapted the part inside the _document_ environment only. I'll remove that line as not to cause possible trouble to others. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to the ones who gave the answers:

[@samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) for the todonotes package information. I implemented in my document as:

```
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=white,linecolor=red,bordercolor=none]{todonotes}
```

Across the document I call it as:

```
\todo{Text}
```

[@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)  for the "\let\marginpar\marginnote". I'm using it inside the figure environment and it worked perfectly.

```
\begin{figure}
    \let\marginpar\marginnote
    \todo[size=\scriptsize]{This is my todo note}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Image.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```